# Implementing a 'kill' button in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm currently working on a PHP UI that gathers information, parses it, sends it off to another program, collects the output and presents it to the user.

Normally it works just fine. Sometimes, though, the other program can take forever to finish (somewhere between 2 and 15 hours, I let it run overnight and it was finished in the morning). I would like to implement a KILL button that allows the user to cancel the program, since not only does it take forever to finish, but ties up the server and prevents the user from doing anything else in the meantime.

The way it's currently set up is like this:
 page1.php gathers all the user input.
 page2.php checks the user input.
   If it's bad, it prints errors.
   If the input is good, it parses it and sends it to the other program with a system call. While this is happening, a 'calculating...' gif appears on screen. Once the program is finished, the output is displayed on the page.

Optimally I would like the kill button to appear at the same time (and only at the same time) as the calculating gif, and I would like it to be able to kill the process (and have the output reflect the fact that the process was killed).

So far I've been able to get the button to appear when and where I'd like it. However, I have not been able to get the actual kill funcitonality that I'm looking for. Currently I have it set up so that the button is made using an html button with a javascript function that executes on click. That javascript function contains php code with a system call which finds the target processes and kills them (I know the system call works properly as I can use it at my terminal window and it works just fine).

Here's the relevant code:

```
startload("calculating");
$opt->run_optimization($output);
stopload("calculating");
```

This puts up the calculating gif and kill button, then runs a function which makes the system call, then removes the calculating gif and kill button.

```
system("./optimi/optimi < $infile > $outfile");
```

This is the system call to the other program (optimi).

```
    print <<< KILLBUTTON

<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="kill();">Kill</button>
<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function kill(){
    <?php
    system("ps -Af | grep optimi | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill"); 
    ?>
}
</script>

KILLBUTTON;
```

This is my kill button, which doesn't seem to do anything at all right now.

I should point out that rewriting the optimi program is something I would like to avoid at all costs, considering I'm not the one who wrote it, nor am I experienced with the programming language it's written in.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `<a href="index.php">Kill Process</a>` ?

Comment: I'd seriously recommend trying to fix the slow program rather than just adding a hacky work-around. Killing a process mid-flow can do nasty things to your data. It may not, but do you know enough about the program to be sure? And if the data still needs to be processed, then killing it doesn't solve any problems anyway, as you'll still need to run the script at some point, and it'll still take just as long.

Answer (score 7):

You don't seem to understand how web servers interact with your browser.

When you send a request to a web server running php, the web server loads up the requested file, interprets any relevant php code, then sends the browser a *text file*.

If there's javascript in that text file, your browser will attempt to interpret / execute it.  You can't put php code in a javascript function and expect it to be executed when the user does something - all php on a page is executed exactly once - when the page is requested.

If you want to run php code in response to a user interaction, you need to set up an ajax request to the php script in question.

Comment: I was busy essentially writing the same reply as this, however, that is not really an answer to the question.  Even if you create a script to do what you want (which is non-trivial because having your apache user be able to escalate itself to root is a very dangerous thing indeed)  I'm not sure that you will get the behavior you want -- which is to have the system() call return.  If that works ok, then you can do what Sam suggests with Ajax (perhaps embedded into the "Calculating"  image by adding an anchor tag around it that kills the process.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and created an AJAX request. However, my kill button still isn't working. The issue, it seems, is that until the program is finished the server doesn't respond to anything else from the user. Even if they try loading up a different page, it still just hangs waiting for the server. How I've gotten past this so far is by sending the kill command through the terminal myself. I was hoping the Kill button could do that instead of me, but it hasnt. Is there some way of having the program execute in such a way that the server doesn't have to wait for it to do anything else?

Comment: @MattS - You might need to separate the system into 3 scripts then - a generic UI page with a "start" button, which sends an ajax request to run the script, and a "kill" button, which sends an ajax request to the kill script.

Comment: @Sam Dufel isn't that basically how I have it set up now? I have a page that gathers the input and has a 'start' button. It loads up a second page that shows 'calculating' until the process is finished, with a button that sends an ajax request to kill the process. The only difference I see between how I have it and what you're suggesting is that the 'submit' button isn't an ajax request.

Comment: Exactly.  You need to have the process start asynchronously, so that you don't don't navigate away from the page with the kill button as soon as the process starts.